# WooCommerce - Add new item to cart for every purchased item

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Current scenario :
A new law in my country obligates me to add a 'Green Stamp' for almost all electrical products that a customer wants to purchase .

At the moment I only got working a percentage, like below .

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
  //global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

    $percentage = 0.0001;
    $surcharge = ( WC()->cart->cart_contents_total + WC()->cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage;    
    WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Green Stamp', $surcharge, true, 'standard' );

}
```

how can I add that custom Green Stamp product with a standard price for all products that a customer adds to cart, MINUS the products in some categs ?!

edited : $woocommerce deprecated

Comment: Maybe [Force Sells](http://www.woothemes.com/products/force-sells/) is in order? Also, `$woocommerce` has  been deprecated in favor of `WC()`.

Comment: i don't want to buy more plugins ... I'm sure there is an easy code way ...